# How to get min-height working in Safari, Chrome on MAC

Tags: macos, safari, css

I have a page with the following CSS, it renders fine on IE and FF, but on Mac in Safari and Chrome the min-height does not seem to work and all the content collapses on top of each other when the browser page is short instead of staying extended and providing scrollbars:

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
   height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    body {
   height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background: #000000;
        font: 86% Arial, "Helvetica Neue", sans-serif;
        margin: 0;   
        padding: 0px;
        color: #CCCCCC;
    }
    #website_wrapper {
        min-height: 850px;
   min-width: 1080px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }
    #website {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #000000;
        vertical-align: bottom;
    }
```

Any ideas why Safari (WebKit I guess) is not doing what it is told to do?
Thanks in advance...

Comment: You have 100% after your min-height. but min-height is bugged out for me in webkit too. just thought I'd point it out.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason I'm encountering as similar issue, where my navbar on Safari is a different height to other browsers.

To fix it I have used `min-height: initial`

I also wrapped this in a safari-specific media query, to avoid possible conflicts:

[is there a css hack for safari only NOT chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome)

Answer (score 1):

The following example works for me on Mac OS X 10.6.4 using Safari 5.0.1 (not sure which version of Webkit):

```
<html>
    <head>
    <!--
        <style>
        .box1 {
            float: left;
            width: 100px;
            margin: 1em 20px 1em 0;
            background: yellow;
            border: 1px solid black;
            min-height: 100px;
        }
    -->
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="box1"></div>
        <div class="box1">less text</div>
        <div class="box1">more text more text more text more text more text more text</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can't tell from your example how you are implementing your styles as you only show your style definitions. Another thing I've noticed is that you are defining ID styles (# notation) instead of class styles (dot notation). Though that also works, it's [recommended](http://www.tizag.com/cssT/cssid.php) that you define class styles when you want to apply a style to multiple elements.

If this example doesn't help you, perhaps you can paste some HTML that shows HOW you are using your styles.

Comment: This helped, thank you!  @meteorainer Just saying that this issue is also bugged for you should really be a comment to the Question instead of an answer: [SO FAQ - on answers that are "thanks!" or "me too!" responses](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion)

Answer (score 0):

min-height is supposed to be supported in Safari now but you might want to try the [underscore hack](http://www.wellstyled.com/css-underscore-hack.html):

min-height: 850px;
height: auto;
_height: 850px;