# Absolutely positioned div not positioned correctly on mac/ios but fine on windows

Tags: html, css

Had this issue for a couple days now but I can't for the life of me figure out what's causing it. A few google searches have pointed me a collapsing margin bug but I thought I'd get a definitive answer or at least get pointed in the right direction.

I have a div that is positioned absolutely within a relative div. This div is position varies from mac to pc.

The below screen shot is on a mac

[image: text out of place.]

The below screen shot is on a windows pc

[image: text in place]

This same issue happens on iOS devices as well, and is consistent across browsers.

```
   <div style="position:relative;" id="section3">
<div class="highheader" style=" font-size:42px;position:absolute; top:-8px; left:25px; color:black;" id="categoryname">VIDEO HIGHLIGHTS</div>
```

Above is a text snippet of the code. For some reason it just appears to be interpretting the top:-8px absolute value differently from machines. It's the same for every div I've set up like this. There is a version of this code up on my server where this issue is happening.

[www.atomichael.com/mmaplus](http://www.atomichael.com/mmaplus)

Anyway I hope the information provided iss helpful enough, if it isn't please don't hesitate to ask for more details!

I really am stumped on this so any help would really be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: more likely a browser variation than the os

Comment: It seems to be caused by the negative top position, but why are you positioning your text over an image? I would use the image as a background image of the box.

Comment: Did you happen to test this in OS-whatever with any other browser than Safari?

Comment: thing is I've tested the same browsers on both platforms (Firefox, Chrome and Safari) and the issue doesn't vary across browsers but does across OS. Same goes for iOS (happens on chrome and safari).

Comment: Yes multiple browsers and Jeroen, I'm a bit of a noob, that would probably prove to be a more elegant setup lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts are not standard. Also, you can add padding, height, or line-height for some adjustments, or even adjust your position. I would start with the font. See:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_websafe_fonts.asp

Comment: Does appear to be an issue with the non standard font. The difference disappears when I revert to a font like Arial. Surely I should be able to fix this my explicitly declaring the padding, height,etc values?

Comment: If anyone else ever encounters this issue I was able to use this site to solve my issue.

http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Fonts have three sets of embedded vertical metrics information and that site tries to synchronise them also giving you the css and  setting up a bullet proof font face

Answer (score 0):

Just set `top:0px` and it will work fine for the following `divs`

```
<div class="highheader" style=" font-size:42px;position:absolute; top:0px; left:25px; color:black;" id="categoryname">VIDEO HIGHLIGHTS</div>

<div class="highheader" style=" font-size:42px;position:absolute; top:0px; left:25px; color:black;" id="categoryname">LATEST NEWS</div>

<div class="highheader" style=" font-size:42px;position:absolute; top:0px; left:25px;" id="categoryname">PLUS BABES</div>

<div class="tileheader" style=" font-size:42px;position:absolute; top:0px; left:25px;" id="categoryname">LATEST POSTS</div>
```

Other option is to create a `class` and apply different css for `chrome` and for `safari`

**Probably this hack can work**

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    /* Safari and Chrome */
    .myClass {
     top:-8px;
    }

    /* Safari only override */
    ::i-block-chrome,.myClass {
     top:0px;
    }
}
```

This is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome/#17472322)

Comment: Not quite. It then displays fine on Mac but becomes 8 pixels lower on windows, which isn't the desired postion :(

Comment: I imagine this hack would work but should probably avoid targeting specific platforms like that... Thanks for the suggestion anyway!