# Target safari css, but not chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari

Ran into a problem, where chrome and safari display margin differently. But both of them are webkit, so can't really use a prefix. Is there any solution, or hack that could help with it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found somewhere else here. worked fine for me

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
/* Safari and Chrome */
.myClass {
 color:red;
}

/* Safari only override */
::i-block-chrome,.myClass {
 color:blue;
}
}
```

Comment: Microsoft Edge also support some features of `-webkit` ... your answer will target MS Edge as well

Comment: Not working for me, but this does: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome