# ::i-block-chrome css trick not working on Mac

Tags: ios, css, macos

Recently I did some css repairs in a site using a CSS trick to target only Safari browsers, some similar to this:

```css
::i-block-chrome, .someclass{
   atribute: value;
}
```

But I discovered that this trick is not working on Mac devices (Macbooks, iPhones or iPads). Anyone here can tell me some alternative to solve this ?

Thanks!

Comment: check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Comment: Thank you @ynos123, i saw the post. It seems this trick only work on Safari 5 or older.

Comment: Try: [1] http://www.paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/ # [2] http://gotoanswer.stanford.edu/?q=is+there+a+css+hack+for+safari+only+NOT+chrome%3F # [3] http://tiku.io/questions/114982/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
 @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
    ::i-block-chrome, .someclass {
   /* Add your style*/
    }
}
```

```html
should be have below the code at <head> section

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```