# Are there specific ways to target a safari browser in css

Tags: css, safari

I am trying to give a safari browser:

```
.selected1 :hover {border-width: 3px;}
```

and the other browsers:

```
.selected1 :hover {border-width: 2px;}
```

I read many ways how you can target a safari browser but also my chrome browser folows the lines. I didn`t find a way to only target a safari browser. Hopefully you guys have one for me!

Thnx

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  It seems like there must be a better method.

Comment: http://borishoekmeijer.nl/how-to-target-a-specific-browser/

Comment: possible duplicate of [is there a css hack for safari only NOT chrome?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s no way to do this directly in CSS. You can detect Safari using JavaScript, e.g. with the following code:

```js
if (!!navigator.userAgent.match(/Version\/[\d\.]+.*Safari/)) {
    document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].className += 'is-safari';
}
```

Then you can do something like this in your CSS:

```css
html.is-safari .selected1 :hover {border-width: 3px;}
```

However, my recommendation is to avoid this. Detecting the user agent string is generally not a good idea.