# HTML Dropdown appears different on OSX

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I have an HTML form with inputs and dropdowns.  All have been styled using CSS.  But for strange reason the dropdown is not responding to the CSS style that I set.  If you look at the screenshot, you will see that the input fields appear correctly, but the dropdown seems to be using some OSX default look and feel which looks way off.  The weird thing is that it appears correctly when I tested it on a windows Machine.  Is there something I should be adding to make this appear correctly on OSX?
[image]

Comment: Can you please create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) or similar?

Comment: Is this similar to what you need http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Comment: @MarkoGrešak here is the jsfiddle, same behaviour https://jsfiddle.net/mxdnw89w/

Comment: @Jared not that's not it.  This is not a Safari issue, does that in Firefox and Chrome, it seems to be an OSX thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the fiddle, I managed to reproduce your problem and also managed to find a fix.

I had to add rule `appearance: none;` to the `select` tag.

```css
.form-field {
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.form-label {
  color: #6E6E6E;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.input1 {
  width: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #3E3E3E;
}

select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;  /* for webkit (safari, chrome) compatibility */
  -moz-appearance: none; /* for firefox compatibility */
  appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-field">
  <div class="form-label">
<span>State *</span>
  </div>
  <div class="form-input">
<select id="state" class="input1">
  <option value="FL" selected="selected">Florida</option>
</select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude, thx so much!! Almost there, one more thing is still broken in the fix, i noticed the dropdown arrow is not showing anymore??

Comment: and also, the edges are curved..?

Comment: Huh, yeah I haven't been paying attention and I though the curved edges were expected. I'm sorry to say, but I'm out of ideas. I always used [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) (or similar, e.g. [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/), [semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/), [material design](http://www.getmdl.io/) etc.) and didn't even have to bother with cross-platform mess.

Comment: I was playing around and doing this at least fixes the rounded corners
select {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;  /* for webkit (safari, chrome) compatibility */
  -moz-appearance: textfield; /* for firefox compatibility */
  appearance: textfield;
}

Comment: Even though it's not the full solution, I'll accept t he answer since at least you allowed me to get over the first big hump which was the variance.  Now that it looks like it belongs into the form, I'll see what I can do about the arrow.

Comment: Thanks! I wish you luck at finishing off the problem. Maybe this link from [CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/appearance/) will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a CSS reset.

There are several ones out there. If you're using HTML5 you probably want Normalize.css: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

If you're using traditional HTML, then the Meyer Reset 2.0 should do: http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Go to the links above and download the file. Link the file before your own styles.

Comment: Tried this.  Doesn't seem to be a reset issue.