# Inline SVG disappears in iOSand Safari when a CSS filter is applied

Tags: css, svg, safari

The situation is I have an inline SVG generated by [Grunticon](https://github.com/filamentgroup/grunticon) and inserted into the DOM. It's white on a grey background with a drop-shadow.

I used the following CSS for the shadow:

```
svg {
  -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #141414);
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0 #141414);
}
```

This works fine in Chrome, Opera, Firefox and everywhere else I've tested it, except Safari on iOS and desktop. The CSS filter makes the SVG disappear.

It's not just the `drop-shadow` filter either, any filter seems to have this effect.

A demo is on Codepen at http://codepen.io/derekjohnson/pen/MyOaRY

Can this be worked round to make it work in Safari?

Comment: Yes, but what's your question here?

Comment: How to make it not disappear! Will update the q for clarification :)

Comment: Remove it when safari is the UA. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Annoying that this doesn't work, but Safari is the new IE after all! :P

A workaround is to wrap the SVG in another element and apply the filter to that.

Comment: Is there an open bug for this behavior in Safari? I am wondering when it will be addressed.

Comment: It appears to be fixed in Safari Technology Preview so we just have to wait a bit

Comment: How do you "wait a bit" with countless users who will not update anything?

Comment: I have the same issue with using  stripe with filter:url(#id) in css to color svg called via <use> tag. strangely, svg works like a charm on one page, and same code does not work on the other page. Cannot figure out why.