# sass interpolation in selector doesn't work

Tags: css, sass

I wanna create a rule for safari browser only with sass. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25975282/3872976) answer I need

> @media screen and (min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)

Notice there's no space after 2nd **and**, otherwise it triggers chrome.
So somewhere in `my-file.sass` I do the following:

```
$safari-only: '(min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)'

@media screen and #{$safari-only}
    body
        background-image: linear-gradient(green 0%, red 100%) !important
```

But this thing compiles into

```
@media screen and (min-color-index: 0) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
  body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(green 0%, red 100%) !important;
  }
}
```

Note, there **IS** a space after 2nd **and**. **Here's the [demo](http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3ddf25510ea9b0e5d9e55f6ac9929ea7)**

Another thing I would like to know if I can create a `@safari-only` mixin. For example:

```
@mixing safari-only
  $safari-only: '(min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)'
  @media screen and #{$safari-only}

@include safari-only
  body
    background-image: linear-gradient(green 0%, red 100%) !important
```

This produces an error that the mixin doesn't have a body

So I would like to know:

1. How do I tell sass not formatting code instead of me?
2. How can I create a first level selector as a mixin

p.s. I'm using `Sass 3.4.21 (Selective Steve)`

Best regards,

Answer (score -1):

You can force formatting in SASS with `#{}`

```
$safari-only: #{'(min-color-index:0) and(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)'}
```

Comment: Could u please edit your answer according my needs? I need to create literal for selector, not for value. `background` is just a highlight example to clear see the difference between in chrome and safari. And as I wrote I used `#{$safari-only}` it doesn't work! If I replace a variable with its value it doesn't change a thing :(

Comment: As I wrote in the question, it doesn't work! it complies into `...) and (-web...`see the `space` after **and**? It breaks all functionality of this browser specific rule. I think you just didn't read my question :)

Comment: Could you please check the demo I added ? http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/3ddf25510ea9b0e5d9e55f6ac9929ea7