# Safari media Query for ipad

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1199px) {}

I want to put Media query only for safari browser for given Size of device.

@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width:1199px) { 
::i-block-chrome,.allsearch-in select{display:none;}
}

still not Working...

Comment: Please go through the link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### CSS Media Queries for iPads & iPhones

#### iPad in portrait & landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px)  { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

#### iPad in landscape

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}
```

#### iPad in portrait

```
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) { /* STYLES GO HERE */ }
```

#### Browser Specific Hacks

```
/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
#diez  { color: red  }
}

 /* iPhone / mobile webkit */
 @media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
  #veintiseis { color: red  }
 }
```

ThankYou

Comment: But, this is also worked in Chrome, i don't want it work for chrome.

Comment: I just want media query only for Safari

Comment: You can follow two guideline for browser specific **css & media query** hacks

Answer (score 0):

Add Class for safari browser to determine browser name by javascript

```
var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase(); 
if (ua.indexOf('safari') != -1) { 
  if (ua.indexOf('chrome') == -1) {
    alert("2"); // Safari
    //add class to body tag
  }
}
```

then use this class in css.