# Input placeholder spacing on mobile safari

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari

**UPDATE: Here's a link to a [minimum reproducible bug](https://github.com/samcorcos/mobile-safari-bug). Instructions for running it are in the readme**

I'm having issues with the bottom padding below an input placeholder on mobile safari. Here's what the input placeholder looks like on mobile safari:

[image]

Here's what the input placeholder looks like on Chrome:

[image]

As you can see there's a significant difference in the space between the placeholder text and the bottom border.

I've tried changing `line-height` as suggested by a few other stackoverflow answers and I've tried changing `padding-bottom` on the `::placeholder` with appropriate vendor prefixes... I'm not sure what else there is to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend not using `line-height` for inputs and buttons as it has major browser inconsistencies. Instead use height and padding to make elements the size you want, but in this case using `margin` should be sufficient once you remove the `line-height` property.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the ticket to include a reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without seeing the code. Have you tried to putting a `margin-bottom` on either the top object or putting a `margin-top` on the input field. 
You will have to put it in a condition for safari browser only though, you can do this directly inside the CSS using - reference here:
[is there a css hack for safari only NOT chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome)

There has to be an underlining problem with this, I experienced something much like this with floats that were 0.1 pixels off between the two browsers which didn't render my grids properly. I fixed it by using fixed values for all the objects: `width` and `height`. I noticed the pencil in the top image is further away from the California than on Chrome.

Comment: Let me see if I can come up with a minimum reproducible error. I tried margin-top and margin-bottom and that didn't seem to solve it.

Comment: I went ahead and updated the ticket to include a reproducible example.