# Slideshow not fullscreen height on Safari, but it is on Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, slideshow

I have a full page homepage slideshow which works perfectly on Firefox and Chrome, however in Safari it does not go the full screen height, having a blank space at the bottom of the browser window, I have attached a screenshot below.

[image: screenshot]

From inspecting it, it appears that the inline css on the slideshow is not generating enough to push it down, however i am not sure how to rectify this as it is just an issue on Safari, please see another screenshot showing the margin-top being too short.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried inspecting it? rightclick inspect element, to see what  happens there?

Comment: @Tschallacka it seems to be the automatically inline css margin-top which isn't enough to push it down into position when I inspect it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome Try modifying the elements with the css hacks outlined here