# How to give css only for safari browser not a chrome

Tags: css, safari

my safari browser version is **5.0**.and my problem is how to give a css for safari browser not a chrome browser.

please, help me.Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a css hack for safari only NOT chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

Use this. It will work only in Safari.

```
/* Css for Safari  */
 @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){
    ::i-block-chrome, .yourClassName {
         background:#f00;
    }
}
```

Comment: i also try this but not solve my problem.actually i give my style in scss.

Answer (score 0):

CSS Selector/Property/Value Hacks are imho problematic, as

- preprocessors like SASS might not work with them
- browsers or browser-versions they apply to, are subject to change

Therefore - if you really need to use browser-specific css - I'd recommend you to use JavaScript to set a certain class to the  or  tag, which is then used by a CSS Selector to style only in these desired browsers.

JS:

```
if(doSomeUserAgentLogic()) {
  document.body.classList.add("is-safari")

}
```

CSS:

```
body.is-safari .custom-selector {
  property: value;
}
```

Detecting the browser and certain versions using the userAgent in JavaScript is not that easy, therefore you should probably use something like https://github.com/DamonOehlman/detect-browser, but at least this way of detecting is "quite" stable.