# Targetting css on iPad Safari only

Tags: css, mobile-safari

I have a form that displays correctly on iPad Chrome and Firefox and on iPhone Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

I need to write the appropriate media query to target only iPad Safari.

The css I'm using is very simple, of the type:

```
.et_pb_contact_right p input.et_pb_content_captcha {
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 2px #F7823A solid;
}
```

How can I make this specific target?

Thanks.

Page is https://passports.edkatzman.com/contact/

Answer (score 0):

Apply the following codeblock to your CSS.

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { 
  @media {

    .safari_only { 

      /* Write your iOS Safari code here */ 

    }
  }
}
```

You can apply the class to elements that need modified in iOS Safari specifically.

See [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25975282/9741508) for more information about this particular hack.

Comment: Hi. It's not working, but I'll study the link you gave me.  Thanks.