# How to include a safari only style in scss ?

Tags: css, sass, safari, cross-browser, stylesheet

I simply wants to modify a styling property for safari browsers only, which will override the default property.

simple example:

**Default**

```
div {
  color: blue;
}
```

**Safari browsers**

```
div {
  color: red;
}
```

I imagine this can be done with the @include function of scss but I am not sure how.

Comment: Take a look on this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Comment: Please refer "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome" for details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome seems like a css question and not sass related, it might be tagged wrong

Comment: my question differs from how I want to implement this, I don't want to affect the root but only a specific class (just the div tag for simplicity). I don't understand how I can use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome and still arrange my sass code as I want.

Comment: `@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm){ @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) { width: 102%; }}` did the trick