# Apply Safari specific styling using React-Radium

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, safari, radium

So I have a form with some input fields. I have set their `font-weight` to `400`. It is working all fine on Chrome and Firefox but on Safari it is bolder. In Safari the `font-weight` is the same as that of other browsers but it is rendering it bolder. I need to change `font-weight` to `300` only on Safari browser. I have found an answer here [CSShack for Safari only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome). But the thing is I am using `Radium` for styling my `React` components. This is my current styling object:

```
input: {
    width: '100%',
    fontFamily: ' HelveticaNeue-Medium,  Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif',
    fontSize: h3_general,
    fontWeight: 400,
    color: '#777777',
    border: '0',
    textIndent: '20px',
    background: '#FFFFFF',
    borderRadius: '4px',
    letterSpacing: '-0.26px',
    textAlign: 'left',
    lineHeight: '22px',
    height: '3rem',
    margin: '0',
    '@media only screen and (max-width: 450px)': {
      fontSize: h3_mobile
    }
  }
```

And I need to add the following CSS to it:

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) { @media {    
    .safari_only {     
        font-weight: 300    
    }
}}
```

How can I do this in Radium?