# CSS for button working on chrome but not on safari

Tags: css, wordpress, button, styling

I am having some problem with a button styling. CSS works perfectly on chrome but not on safari / safari: https://prnt.sc/ku3bhl, chrome: https://prnt.sc/ku3wjj / 
Here is the code I am using / I am basically overwriting some of it's styles that it get's from it's plugin:

```
.popover-markup2215 button {
    background: #fff !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
    border-color: #111 !important;
    padding: 12px !important;
    margin-bottom: -177px !important;
    margin-left: 119px !important;
}
```

example link: https://graveren.mmcreaties.nl/product/iphone-7-telefoonhoesje-ontwerpen-zwart/

Comment: I guess this answer might help you. You need certain css hack to run css in Safari browser. https://stackoverflow.com/a/25975282/9945519

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see from the dev tools the class name is: `.popover-markup2214` and not 2215, or if the class is changing dynamically try to get it like this `.cart .trigger.btn`

Comment: thank you! Didn't noticed that it is added dynamically on each product, when i changed my class and added css hack for Safari everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Add this CSS.

you need to use `-webkit-appearance`

```
.single_add_to_cart_button {
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    text-transform: lowercase;
    border: 2px solid #796eff !important;
    box-shadow: 7px 7px 0 rgba(79, 84, 124, 0.4) !important;
    background: #796eff !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    width: 40%;
    border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

Comment: Sorry i meant about this button, no the add to cart button : http://prntscr.com/ku9b6y