# CSS not working in Safari, working fine in Chrome

Tags: css, angular

The above CSS is working fine for both Chrome and Mozilla, but it's not working for Safari.

Mozilla:

```css
@supports (-moz-appearance:none) {
  .additem .additem_btn i:before {
    font-size: 14px !important;
    margin-left: -2px !important;
  }
}
```

Safari:

```css
_::-webkit-full-page-media,
_:future,
 :root .additem .additem_btn i:before {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-left: -2px !important;
}
```

All browsers:

```css
.additem .additem_btn i:before {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin-left: -1px !important;
}
```

Original design:

[image]

Issues are marked in red color:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Comment: Look like this not a browser issue there is something wrong with in your code, can you please create a snippet so we can help you out.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [is there a css hack for safari only NOT chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome)

Comment: This is the snippet for the above screen. https://jsfiddle.net/praveepradeep/yt1jr59v/1/