# Old webkit browser that do not support flex-wrap

Tags: html, css, flexbox, webkit

My current html works fine with bootstrap 4 wrapping and creating a two column layout. Problem is with older browsers that do not support bootstrap or flex and use an older version of webkit.

What is the alternative or equivalent to `flex-wrap: wrap;` and `-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;` for old webkit browsers like Safari 5 on Windows or Midori on Windows/Linux?

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row box-container">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">Item 1</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 2</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 3</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 4</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 5</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This gives me an output of two columns... standard bootstrap

```
item 1   item 2
item 3   item 4
```

Non-bootstrap browsers like Midori or older versions of Safari using webkit
outputs the following...

```
item 1   item 2    item 3    item 3
```

Comment: See this page [https://browserl.ist](https://browserl.ist/) and ask yourself if you are sure you want to support sites as old as safari 5. If so then maybe don't use bootstrap and new css only make a website just like you did 20 years ago - everything on the tables. You will be sure that it works everywhere;)

Comment: @GrzegorzT. I have no choice but to support it is pre-installed on an old device that I do not have access to for updating. this is not by choice, I would rather not he to apply so many hacks to get this to work.

Comment: Take a look here [browsers-devices](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/). The only solution is to detect the browser in javascript and add a separate css that will overwrite the bootstrap for these browsers.

Comment: Can you try including bootstrap 3 for only those browsers ?

Answer (score 6):

### How to get the desired layout in Safari 5

[Safari 5's implementation of flexbox does not support wrapping](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) so your only option is to use flexbox for the browsers that support it and gracefully fallback to another method in older browsers.

### Approach 1

One way you can do this is by adding `float: left;` to `.col-6` (this will get ignored by browsers using `flex`) and reverting `.row` to `display: block;`; you can then use `@supports (display: flex)` to set browsers that support flexbox back to using it.

```css
.row {
  display: block;
}

.col-6 {
  float: left;
}

@supports (display: flex) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row box-container">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">Item 1</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 2</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 3</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 4</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 5</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle example (click on "Result")](https://jsfiddle.net/6be1gdut/embedded)

### Approach 2

If you are just interested in handling old versions of Safari, you could use a [CSS hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17472322/3400962) that only those particular versions of Safari understand to target them:

```css
::i-block-chrome,
.row {
  display: block;
}

::i-block-chrome,
.col-6 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row box-container">
  <div class="col-6">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-6">Item 1</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 2</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 3</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 4</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 5</div>
      <div class="col-6">Item 6</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle example (click on "Result")](https://jsfiddle.net/6be1gdut/1/embedded/)

### That said...

I wouldn't spend too much time looking to fix problems in obsolete browsers as you are likely to expend a lot of effort for very little gain. Graceful degradation is nice but if you endeavour to support every browser under the sun you'll be fixing issues that very few people (or no-one!) will actually be seeing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a 2 column layout and to support browsers that don't support flex box, you could do away with flex box and just use:

```
display: inline-block;
width: 50%; // note: ensure you have no whitespace between elements in html
```

or

```
float: left;
width: 50%;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi i have check for the older version of browsers you are mention in your question this code display content as you required.

```
.row {
  display: box;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-lines: multiple;
  display: run-in;
}
.col-6 {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0.0;
  -webkit-box-flex-group: 2;
  -webkit-box-lines: single;
  float: left;
}
```

but the problem is that it will affect on the latest version of all browser. and in a blog i also read that Safari 5 for windows or Midori windows/linux are not support the new syntax of flexbox it support the older syntax. Blog Link: https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, the equivalent of `flex-wrap:wrap;` or `-webkit-flex-wrap:wrap` in Safari 5 should be `-webkit-box-lines:multiple` going by the then current [2009 flex-box specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-css3-flexbox-20090723/#propdef-box-flex-group). However, this doesn't work **not** based on my tests and other reliable sources ([caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)).

The best way to replicate the flex-wrap behaviour consistently across as many browsers as possible is to use the `display:inline-block` css rule on every sibling of the flexible container. There will be no major difference between the flex-box version and the inline-block version except for a 1em space that is automatically added between each and every element in the inline-block version.

```css
/*Asthetic code starts*/
html{
  font-family:sans-serif;
}
div div{
  margin:2.5px;
  padding:5px;
  background:#f2f2f2;
}
/*Asthetic code ends*/
/*Actual code*/
.container-1{
  display:flex;
}
.container-2 div{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h3>Flex-box example</h3>
<div class="container-1">
<div class="child">Item 1</div>
<div class="child">Item 2</div>
<div class="child">Item 3</div>
<div class="child">Item 4</div>
</div>
<h3>Same thing implemented using <code>inline-block</code></h3>
<div class="container-2">
<div class="child">Item 1</div>
<div class="child">Item 2</div>
<div class="child">Item 3</div>
<div class="child">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: if we are use inline-block then what is the need of bootstrap 4 we can implement it with bootstrap 3 instead of bootstrap 4.