# How to hide css style for all safari browsers

Tags: html, css, wordpress, safari

I have applied some css to make my footer at bottom (fixed position). when someone scrolled down, I have applied effect like, the footer is fixed on his position and the page wrapper (page end) will move up (up to footers height) from the bottom.

Below is the css:

```
    .site-footer{
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index:-1;

}

body #page_wrapper{
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom:420px;
    background:#ffffff;
    z-index:1;
}
```

But, this effect won't work in safari browser.
So, I have to apply this css for all the other browsers except safari. Means I want, safari runs with the default footer (without above effects).
How can I hide the above css for safari browser? Suggest!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [is there a css hack for safari only NOT chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome)

Comment: Thanks Awais, I am using @supports (-webkit-marquee-repetition:infinite) and (object-fit:fill) { } for safari and it's working.