# CSS full height doesn't work in all browsers

Tags: html, css

I try to make a view fill 100vh in every device at every browser.
I found the solution to do like this.

```
html {
    height: 100vh;
    height: -moz-available; 
    height: -webkit-fill-available; /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
    height: -moz-available; /* Mozilla-based browsers will ignore this. */
    height: -webkit-fill-available; /* WebKit-based browsers will ignore this. */
}
```

It works correctly in Chrome but in Safari on iPad it looks like this.

[image]

It should be like this:
[image]

Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you!

Comment: What's wrong in the screenshot? It might help to share what it should look like.

Comment: oh, it should be over the whole white area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari uses a WebKit engine; remove `height: -webkit-fill-available;`

Comment: Then it won't work in firefox, yes?

Comment: @TorNato Apologies pasted the wrong code.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work... I have to scroll a little bit at safari on iPad. I updated the question

Comment: @jansemrau Change the height in that case but in this class ```_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .safari_only ``` For more info refer to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-css-hack-for-safari-only-not-chrome

Comment: @jansemrau I would adivse you to increase the height to auto.

Comment: The problem still exists... The thing is, that it is not a specific safari problem. It is a safari problem on the iPad...

Comment: @jansemrau In that case take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37112218/css3-100vh-not-constant-in-mobile-browser

Comment: @jansemrau can you accept the answer if it helped you out please? Just click on the tick. Thank you and You're welcome!