# CSS hack that also supports IOS16

Tags: css, media-queries, ios16

This CSS hack used to work up to iOS 15.6, but it doesn't work in iOS 16.

```
@media not all and (min-resolution:.001dpcm) {
    @supports (-webkit-appearance:none) {}
}
```

Are there any new hacks to also target Safari 16?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

some Hyphenation seems like it does work only on safari.. honestly, I have never used them but take a look at it from here
https://caniuse.com/?search=-webkit-hyphens

someone also was suggesting this

```
@supports (-webkit-hyphens:none){
        @content
}
```

[Is there a way to apply styles to Safari only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348489/is-there-a-way-to-apply-styles-to-safari-only?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top)

Comment: This seems to be working. Tested it on browserstack and it works in iOS16 down to iOS 10 which is the older version of iOS browserstack supports. It applies to both Safari and Chrome browsers in iOS. Thanks for the help.

Comment: you are always welcome. i am glad i could help :)